# How to run a batch command with parameters from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch

I'm writing up a PowerShell script that will run [ElasticSearch's Support Diagnostics](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-support-diagnostics) tool on demand.

Here is my code:
ES.Config.xml - This is an xml file that stores the diagnostic command that I want to run from PowerShell. Its stored as a string (See DEV.Diagnostic.ExecuteCommand:

```
<DEV>
<Diagnostic FolderPath="" ExecuteCommand="C:\ElasticSearch\support-diagnostics-5.12\diagnostics.bat  --host localhost --port 9200  --user elastic -p"  />
```

In my powershell script I'm trying to run the command as:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command $global:DiagnosticCommand
```

$global:DiagnosticCommand is a global variable that stores the value "C:\ElasticSearch\support-diagnostics-5.12\diagnostics.bat  --host localhost --port 9200  --user elastic -p"

I always get an error when I run this command. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: **I always get an error …**: what error? Where it comes from? From `powershell` or from [diagnostics.bat](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-support-diagnostics/blob/master/scripts/diagnostics.bat) or from `java`? Please [edit] the question and provide full traceback.

Comment: I recommend looking at the `call` operator.

Comment: The error that I keep getting is the following:  Error: Could not find or load main class com.elastic.support.diagnostics.DiagnosticApp.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure the context you'd use this in, perhaps a few examples would help below.  I've seen two key commandlets which may help you.  I put in an example which doesn't need an explicit path, though you can point to the full path with parameters for either ArgumentList or -ScriptBlock {enter your full executable and parameters here}

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mstsc.exe -ArgumentList "/?" 
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/?"

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mstsc.exe /?}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {msiexec.exe /?}
```

In your case can you try the following?

```
Invoke-Command -ScripBlock{
C:\ElasticSearch\support-diagnostics-5.12\diagnostics.bat  --host localhost --port 9200  --user elastic -p}
```

You can reference the full technet white papers for both commandlets:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-5.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: When I ran your script, I get the following error:                                                    C:\ElasticSearch\support-diagnostics-5.12\diagnostics.bat  --host localhost --port 9200  --user elastic -p folder exists
JAVA_HOME found, using C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141
Error: Could not find or load main class com.elastic.support.diagnostics.DiagnosticApp, but when I run this command in its own command window, this runs fine.

Comment: "Could not find or load main class com.elastic.support.diagnostics.DiagnosticApp" is an error from Java, and my Java skills are not good enough to provide you end-to-end troubleshooting.  Powershell supports creating classes, however it does not need a method such as the classic  "public static void main" so the error you're having will have to be dealt with from the perspective of your Elastic class.